# Comparing templated types without taking in consideration template arguments

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

Is it possible in `C++` to compare two types without taking in consideration is template arguments? Take this example:

```
struct Kilogram: public mass<Kilo, kg> {
    using dimension = mass;
    using ratio = Kilo;
};
struct Hectogram: public mass<Kilo, kg> {
    using dimension = mass;
    using ratio = Hecto;
};
```

So, in a concept, I want to check that both types belongs to the same dimension `mass`, so I could be able to performn transformations in types related by their dimension, but I could not with different dimensions.

```
template <typename T>
    concept Magnitude = requires {
        typename T::dimension;
        typename T::ratio;
    };

    template <typename T, typename R>
    concept SameMagnitude = requires {
        requires Magnitude<T> && Magnitude<R>;
        requires std::is_same_v<typename T::dimension, typename R::dimension>;
    };
```

I explored SFINAE options with `std::true_type` and `std::false_type`, *tag dispathching*, but they don't suffice to me, as the tag dispatching one will make me inherit from another type, let's say, `mass_dimension`, so my public API starts to be more and more complicated, and I will like to make things as simpler as possible.

How can I compare that both categories have the same dimension of mass, but without taking in consideration the template arguments for the mass type?

EDIT:
Where mass:

```
template<Ratio prefix, Symbol S>
class base_magnitude {}; /* ... more types to represent ratios and symbols */

template <Ratio R, Symbol S>
class mass: public base_magnitude<R, S> {};
```

So, if I have a new "dimension":

```
template <Ratio R, Symbol S>
class length: public base_magnitude<R, S> {};
```

I wanted to performn operations on mass magnitudes, for example, adding grams and kilograms, but detect whenever any type has not the same dimension, let's say, adding meters to kilograms will make fail the concept, because:

```
struct Kilogram: public mass<Kilo, kg> {
    using dimension = mass;
    using ratio = Kilo;
};
struct Kilometer: public length<Kilo, km> {
    using dimension = length;
    using ratio = Kilo;
};
```

but, as I said before, I still want to yield true in my concept for types that shares the same dimension, as in the previous example, `Kilogram` and `Hectogram` must yield true, since both are subtypes of mass.

My problem is that the `using dimension = mass` is really:

```
Kilogram -> using dimension = mass<Kilo, kg>...
Hectogram -> using dimension = mass<Hecto, hg>...
```

so the concept should validate that both have the same dimension `mass`, but since my type receives template arguments, they are not the same type.

Comment: `std::is_same_v< A::dimension, B::dimension>` ? Its not completely clear waht you want to compare. Can you add an example that should yield `true` and one that should yield `false` ? And what is `mass` ?

Comment: Sure, one minute

Comment: actually I find it confusion that you do inherit from `mass` **and** have it as alias member, though might be due to details left out here

Comment: I could check for `std::is_base_of...`, but I have the same problem with the template arguments, so that alias is the result of trying to use the `std::same_v` to the types, but since they are aliases, I ended in the same place. Sorry about sharing without refactoring those details, but I am not a C++ experienced developer, and I am trying things until some makes sense for my public API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make a generic trait to check if two types are based on the same template:

```cpp
template<class T, class U>
struct same_template {
    static auto test(...) -> std::false_type;

    template<template<class...> class C, class... R1s, class... R2s>
    static auto test(C<R1s...>, C<R2s...>) -> std::true_type;

    static constexpr bool value = decltype(test(std::declval<T>(),
                                                std::declval<U>()))::value;
};

template<class T, class U>
inline constexpr bool same_template_v = same_template<T, U>::value;

template<class T, class U>
concept SameTemplate = same_template_v<T, U>;
```

Example:

```cpp
template<class T, class U>
requires SameTemplate<T, U>
void Foo(T&&, U&&) {

}

int main() {
    //Foo(Kilometer{}, Kilogram{}); // Error
    Foo(Gram{}, Kilogram{});        // Ok (after you've added `Gram`)
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/GMo1zh3oP)

Comment: Wow. Basically, you've been kind enough to go look at the original source code, and make a simply perfect answer, where I just need to plug the type trait into my code... and it just works. Even more, I made some changes to the last push to my repo, but still fitted perfectly. You diserve much more than a approve and a upvote. Thanks for such amazing way of making a response.

Comment: @AlexVergara You're welcome! Glad it helped! _"...look at the original source code..."_ - Yes, I admit I cheated :-)

Comment: No, that's not cheat. That's been a kind person! Thanks again mate :)

Answer (score 3):

I didnt get your code to compile, but I think I understand what it does. You can use partial specialization to check if two types are instantiations of the same template. The inheritance in your code is not that relevant when the member alias `dimension` can be used for the comparison (which is much simpler). No concepts, only basic template stuff, but I suppose the idea can be translated to more modern c++ without too much effort:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <int x>
struct foo {};

struct A { using dimension = int; };
struct B { using dimension = foo<0>; };
struct C { using dimension = foo<1>; };

template <typename S,typename T>
struct same_dimension_template_impl : std::false_type {};

template <template <int> typename X,int a,int b>
struct same_dimension_template_impl<X<a>,X<b>> : std::true_type {};

template <typename A,typename B>
constexpr bool same_dimension_template_v = same_dimension_template_impl< typename A::dimension, typename B::dimension>::value;


int main() {
    std::cout << same_dimension_template_v<A,B>;
    std::cout << same_dimension_template_v<A,C>;
    std::cout << same_dimension_template_v<B,C>;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/sE1KPdWe5)

Comment: Here you have the source code if you need a version of the code that actually compiles. https://github.com/Pyzyryab/Zero/tree/physics-library/zero/ifc/physics
BTW, thanks for your answer. I am able to understand what is doing, but (due to my noob level in C++ TMP) I will need some time to "translate" it to C++20 onwards

Comment: @AlexVergara btw In case you need the trait to work with any type... I didnt consider the possibililty of no `dimension` member alias being present, it would add just another check, and I didnt consider it as essential for the answer.